# Do not publish sqlproj

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, publish, sqlproj

I have a solution with multiple csproj and one sqlproj file. I am trying to build it with command:

```
msbuild test.sln -target:Clean;Build;Publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /m
```

And I get an error: The "SqlPublishTask" task was not given a value for the required parameter "SqlPublishProfilePath".

So I want to tell MSBuild that I don't want to publish sqlproj. I can easily do it for csproj (just set "PublishableProject" property to false). But it does not work for sqlproj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it may be easier to specify which projects you actually want to publish by only calling the solution targets for these specific projects.

e.g.

```
msbuild test.sln -target:Clean;Build;My_Test_Proj:Publish;solutionfolder\other_proj:Publish
```

See [How to: Build specific targets in solutions by using MSBuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019) on how to construct solution target definitions (e.g. replacing `.` with `_`)